# What happens if I assign two DBI connections in a row to a variable?

Tags: perl, dbi

What happens to the first connection if I assign two `DBI` connections in a row to a variable?
It doesn't feel like there is an implicit `disconnect` (no lag).

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn, $user, $pass );
$dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn, $user, $pass );
```

Comment: Perhaps check the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#disconnect)?

Comment: Try it and find out. Watch your databases connection log (if it has such a thing).

Answer (score 2):

The destructors of DBDs do close the connection.

I mean, it's possible that there's a DBD that leaks database connections out there, but that's highly unlikely and it would be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

One may connect multiple times with the exact same parameters. So I don't see a reason for `connect` to be checking whether there is any existing connection, and certainly not to touch (disconnect) it.

However, the object for this new connection then overwrites the Perl variable `$dbh`.  At this point anything could happen since `DBI` uses `tie`-ed variables, but I don't see in sources that this would trigger the destructor (`DESTROY` method) nor can I see that in drivers' sources that I looked up (`mySQL` and `Postgresql`).

So it seems to me that in this way the handle on the first connection is just lost, and you effectively got a leak.  If that is the case then it is also undefined what happens to possibly open transactions in the first connection.

So I'd add a check on `$dbh` before connecting, using (`defined` and) `state` and/or `ping`.  Then, if previous work with it is indeed done and you want to overwrite it, first close it if needed. (Another option is to structure your code so that a new connection goes into a newly declared variable.)